# Under what circumstances can a diminished 5th move to a perfect 5th in voice leading and harmony?

Tags: voice-leading

There seems to be some exceptions to when the diminished 5th does not resolve and moves to a perfect 5th. The progression with parallel 10ths I V43 I6 with ^3 ^4 ^5 in the top voice seems to be the main example but what about when the progression is reversed? And under what other circumstances can a D5 move to a P5?

Answer (score 2):

Two examples that came to my mind:

1. Common tone resolution of a diminished (seventh) chord, e.g. Co7 resolving to C (or some variation of it), in which case upper note of C-Gb moves to C-G.
2. Dominant seventh chord resolving to tonic with 4-3 suspension, e.g. G7 to Csus4 (to C), in which case F-B resolves first to F-C and only then to E-C. Not sure if it counts, since eventually the tritone resolves to the sixth, but the intermediate step contains the requested movement.

I think there must be some other examples where b5 → 5 movement is forced by some other voice leading rules. In these two examples it results directly from the harmony.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for thanks. I havent gotten to those more advanced chord progressions yet but will keep them in my mind for when I do.