# How to write I vii°6 I6 with the outer voices in parallel 10ths

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

I know that V43 is a better option but the exercise I am doing does not allow me the option of inverted 7 chords. Can someone please correct me if I have made a mistake?

Comment: Related question given the nature of armani's proposed part-writing solution here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118251/under-what-circumstances-can-a-dimished-5th-move-to-a-perfect-5th-in-voice-leadi

Comment: Dekka that is not the same at all. In the other question I thought it might be nice to get a list of exceptions going ... that is a general question regarding those two intervals, it just happens to use that progression.

Comment: are the 2notes in the bass line also eighth notes? Are the Roman numbers given or is this your task? If you are free you can treat the melody note C in B-C-D as passing tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems here! You obviously can't double the F♯, and doubling the bass A would lead to parallels, so your only option is to double the C.

But there is one caveat: some traditions are really strict about motion from a diminished fifth to a perfect fifth, and thus they may view the upper-voice motion (soprano and tenor) moving into the I<sup>6</sup> to be an error. I don't remember what Aldwell and Schachter say, but you'll want to clarify that they "allow" this if you're trying to follow that book exactly.

For me, I see this motion far too often in the literature to treat it as a part-writing error. There are chords later on where you *can't* resolve the tritone "correctly," and for that reason I personally think outlawing d5–P5 motion is pretty unnecessary.

Comment: They say that because of the parallel 10ths in the outer voices the D5 is allowed to move to a P5.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what the grader is looking for, but unfortunately I do see indirect crossed voices with the alto voice going to the C which crosses the soprano's B in the first beat. I to vii6 is quite tricky for sure.